# Eclipse editText remove focus (cursor) when done is pressed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-edittext, focus

i'm pretty new with Eclipse and i have to hide the cursor by clearing the focus in the editText after the done button is pressed in the soft keyboard.

I found that this code work for others:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
        //Clear focus here from edittext
         editText.clearFocus();
    }
return false;
}
});
```

the code of the activity

```
package com.iprogettisti.cppp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;

public class VisualizzaPagina extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (MainActivity.TipoPagina == 1) {
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_visualizza_pagina);            
    }
    else if (MainActivity.TipoPagina == 2) {
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_visualizza_pagina2);           
    }
    else if (MainActivity.TipoPagina == 3) {
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_visualizza_pagina3);           
    }
    else if (MainActivity.TipoPagina == 4) {
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_visualizza_pagina4);           
    }
    else if (MainActivity.TipoPagina == 5) {
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_visualizza_pagina5);           
    }

    edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            //Clear focus here from edittext
             edittext.setCursorVisible(false);
        }
    return false;
    }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.visualizza_pagina, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_visualizza_pagina, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

but i cant figure it out how to get that work.
Where should i place that code? And also give me an errore at the first line "editText" as not reconized, i tryied to give that the unique ID of my edittext but it didnt worked.

Comment: post your code - activity

Comment: Dude you need to learn java first editText is a referance of EditText class which you need to initialize first using EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.myedittext); also You need to import EditText class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
    EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1<your unique ID>);


    edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                //Clear focus here from edittext
                 edittext.setCursorVisible(false);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    edittext.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                edittext.setCursorVisible(true);
                return false;
            }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks this work well but, now if i edit again the text no cursor will be show, beacouse obviusly i have to setCursorVisible to true, how can i catch the onClick event on the edittext field?

Comment: Please find my update and let me know if this works as how you require.

Comment: If it worked please mark the answer right so that others can be benefited from this answer when they search similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find your view by id within (or after) the onCreate().

Move `EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);` inside your `onCreate()` after the `super.onCreate()`